# MagicalRecord sample app will not compile in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, magicalrecord

I downloaded a copy of MagicalRecord repository (commit 946d862cdf3665da52ce14a98c0bfba425bc09fb), but I cannot compile the MagicalRecord sample iOS app (Recipes) in Xcode 7.2 (7C68). I get the following compile errors:

> ...
>   MagicalRecord-master/Samples/iOS/Application/Support/Recipes-Prefix.pch:14:13:
>   'CoreData+MagicalRecord.h' file not found

I am also getting a warning about updating to recommended settings. I updated the project to the recommended settings, but still got the same error.

I tried various paths to CoreData+MagicalRecord.h, but Xcode can't seem to find it. I searched the repository and I can't find it either. I tried:

```
#import <MagicalRecord.h>
```

This directive doesn't throw and error, but now I get this error message:

> ... MagicalRecord-master/MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h:17:9:
>   'MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordXcode7CompatibilityMacros.h' file not
>   found

MagicalRecord.h includes these lines of code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

//! Project version number for MagicalRecord.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MagicalRecordVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for MagicalRecord.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MagicalRecordVersionString[];

#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordXcode7CompatibilityMacros.h>
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordInternal.h>
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordLogging.h>
...
```

I have tried various paths to MagicalRecordXcode7CompatibilityMacros.h, but Xcode cannot find the header. I searched the repository and it is in there at:  MagicalRecord-master/MagicalRecord/Core/MagicalRecordXcode7CompatibilityMacros.h

Please help me get the sample code working. Thank you.

Comment: You have downloaded the Framework of Magical record or installed using cocoapods?

Comment: I downloaded the Framework and tried to run the sample app included with with the Framework.

Comment: @sebrenner -- did you ever solve this?  I'm having problems where Xcode 7.2 refuses to find a header that is right it appears to have the correct path for.

Comment: I'm add MagicalRecord to my project via cocoa pods and it works fine. Other way, if you just copy a directory in your project, delete first path component "MagicalRecord/" and then xCode offer you replace brackets <> with "", but this is annoing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I replace all the < with "

Example:

```
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordXcode7CompatibilityMacros.h>
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordInternal.h>
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordLogging.h>
```

Becomes:

```
#import "MagicalRecordXcode7CompatibilityMacros.h"
#import "MagicalRecordInternal.h"
#import "MagicalRecordLogging.h"
```

Once this was done in every MR file, it worked.  You'll probably want a backup in case pods updates it.

It take a while, but it worked.